# Seeking a quote of Hegel on Descartes

Tags: descartes, hegel

Descartes *The Passions of the Soul* [1:31] suggested the pineal gland could mediate interaction between mind and body.  Published works and lectures of Hegel's discuss that several times (as shown by easy Google search).  But I have a memory that at one point Hegel says something like: when we do not understand a thing we are apt to imagine it is very small.  I am travelling with difficult web access and without my books of course.  So I wonder if anyone here can confirm  my memory with a citation?

Comment: Poked around the Internet for a while. Found nothing even close. Do you remember anything else about Hegel's quote? Most likely books or essays that it might appear in, for example?

Comment: Almost all I know of Hegel is from reading him.  But he discusses Descartes in many places.